# Seam tape on tent fly

Tags: tents, maintenance

I've got a Kelty Typhoon 2 tent, from the mid-1990s but still in good shape. I haven't noticed any leaking from the fly, but I'm thinking it might be time to re-seal the seams on the fly before I take it out in a Vancouver Island winter storm where there's sure to be lots of rain.

I've noticed that the tape covering the fly seams is coming off. If I'm going do  any work on the fly, should I be making sure to re-stick the tape, can I get replacement tape, or will seam sealant provide enough protection?

Comment: Start by making sure what waterproofing is used on your tent. Since it is tape-sealed, it is probably PU, so seam grip should be fine. But it could also be silicone, in which case you need sil-net or equivalent. Or a mix of both, which is more complicated to seam-seal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seam sealant should do just fine.  I use [this particular one](http://www.rei.com/product/603034/gear-aid-seam-grip-seam-sealer) which has worked well for a number of patch jobs.  If the exist tape is dirty or damaged then you will want to trip it off and put on new tape.  It will interfere with getting good seal.

Comment: Ok so is the tape an important part of the waterproofing? Wasn't sure if sealant alone would be enough.

Comment: The sealant alone is fine for waterproofing.  The tape is an important part of structural integrity.